# formula to calculate number of months record is untouched

Tags: formula

i have a formula field that returns number of months record untouched. For smaller dates (within last 3 years range) it is working fine, if the date exceeds 4 years then result is exceeding a month, which shouldn't be. Any idea is appreciated.

Here is the current logic,

```
FLOOR(TODAY() - Date__c) / 30.4368
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

This is most probably due to leap years. You are using the average amount of days in a month, but this is not taking into account leap years.

As an alternative, consider this formula, which uses `YEAR` and `MONTH` functions instead of depending on days:

```
12*(YEAR(TODAY()) - YEAR(Date__c))
+
(MONTH(TODAY()) - MONTH(Date__c))
```